# I made my own version of jquery tabs but I need external link to show tab content & style original nav

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I attempted to add onto this tabs script in jquery that I found. Seems like I've complicated it more than it needs to be. I know this is very easy to do with jquery tabs but I have attempted to make my own version to learn. The vertical tabs work fine but I need the bottom links to do the same thing as the vertical nav buttons & change nav button styling like vertical nav does including background color,etc. There will be external links at the bottom in #footer so keep that in mind as well.

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BD4QS/2/)

```
 $(function(){

 // This is for when vertical navigation on left side of #content is clicked 
 $('#sidemenu a').on('click', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();

 if($(this).hasClass('open')) {
  // do nothing because the link is already open
 } else {
  var oldcontent = $('#sidemenu a.open').attr('href');
  var newcontent = $(this).attr('href');


  $(oldcontent).fadeOut('fast', function(){
    $(newcontent).fadeIn('fast').removeClass('hidden');
    $(oldcontent).addClass('hidden');
  });


  $('#sidemenu a').removeClass('open');
  $(this).addClass('open');
  }
 });

 // This is for when bottom links are clicked
 $('#footer a').on('click', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var oldcontent = $('#sidemenu a.open').attr('href');
 var newcontent = $(this).attr('href');
 // Check if $(this) element links to a tab content or external
 if($(this).hasClass('open-tab')){
     if (oldcontent == newcontent){
        // If this tab is already open, do nothing to page
     } else {
         $('#content ' + String(oldcontent)).fadeOut('fast', function(){
         $(newcontent).fadeIn('fast').removeClass('hidden');
         $('#content ' + String(oldcontent)).addClass('hidden');
         });

         $('#sidemenu a').removeClass('open');
         $('#sidemenu a ' + newcontent).addClass('open');
     }
 } else{ 
   //just use href link to whatever the element's href attribute is
   window.open($(this).attr('href'));
 }


 });


 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your `#footer` links aren't working as well as your `#sidebar` links is because of this line within your `#footer` and `#sidebar` click function:

`var oldcontent = $('#sidemenu a.open').attr('href');`

It's trying to find the current content by checking the classes of the child elements of `#sidebar`.

If you click on a link from the bottom, the next link you click (on the `#sidebar` OR the `#footer`) isn't going to be able to find the current content - because it's not in `#sidebar`, it's in `#footer`. You need a way to assign `var oldcontent` based on both your `#sidebar` **and** your `#footer` elements.